# Alder Lake sound in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 23.04

I have no sound from my new laptop. Not sure what's going on here. It's an HP Envy 16 with a 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900H. Any help is appreciated.

Hardware Info:
lspi -v:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8be5
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 208, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at 622d1d0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 622d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22be (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8be5
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17, IOMMU group 19
        Memory at 6e000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [160] Data Link Feature <?>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

lshw:

```
*-multimedia
     description: Multimedia audio controller
     product: Intel Corporation
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 1f.3
     bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
     logical name: card1
     logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
     logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
     logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D2
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D31p
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D4p
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D5p
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D6c
     logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D7c
     version: 01
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=32
     resources: iomemory:620-61f iomemory:620-61f irq:208 memory:622d1d0000-622d1d3fff memory:622d000000-622d0fffff
```

lsmod:

```
nd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp    28672  4
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common    20480  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      45056  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_sof_probes         20480  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   192512  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   118784  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common   188416  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
soundwire_intel        57344  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               311296  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_probes,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    81920  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_core          417792  8 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_probes,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_compress           32768  2 snd_soc_core,snd_sof_probes
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     94208  2
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          61440  1
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         204800  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core          139264  11 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               192512  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi    16384  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c    16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41    49152  2 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi
snd_rawmidi            53248  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls    20480  1 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41
snd_seq                94208  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
cs_dsp                 65536  2 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41,snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_soc_cs35l41_lib    36864  3 snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_i2c,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41_spi
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   135168  30 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_hda_scodec_cs35l41,snd_timer,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_hda_cs_dsp_ctls,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd
```

journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"

```
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: cs35l41-hda: probe of i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.0 failed with error -22
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: Error: ACPI _DSD Properties are missing for HID CSC3551.
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: cs35l41-hda: probe of i2c-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1 failed with error -22
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input35
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input36
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input37
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0/input38
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: autoconfig for ALC245: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:    inputs:
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0:      Mic=0x19
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: sink widget AIF1TX overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source widget AIF1RX overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi3 overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi2 overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi1 overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Codec Output Pin1 overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Codec Input Pin1 overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Analog Codec Playback overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Digital Codec Playback overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Alt Analog Codec Playback overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Analog Codec Capture overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Digital Codec Capture overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Alt Analog Codec Capture overwritten
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: hda_dsp_hdmi_build_controls: no PCM in topology for HDMI converter 3
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input40
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input41
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input42
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input43
Oct 07 09:55:19 Envious kernel: input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card1/input44
```

Screenshot of Sound Devices:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Attach the output of this command: `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"`

Comment: Added it to the main post.

Comment: The first thing you should do is make sure you have the latest version of BIOS installed

Comment: Yes, I have the latest BIOS installed.